# WAMP server: change wireless SSID and server not reachable

Tags: android, laravel, wamp, wifi, ssid

This is a really strange thing. 
I got a working WAMP server on my laptop, installed Laravel and a web application available to my clients on the local wireless network. Everything is working flawlessy. I can communicate between my android app via the wireless AP TP-Link to the WAMP server. No need of internet, this is a LAN just for devices behind.
Now, I decide to change the SSID of the AP. Change from "Zapp" to "Polls". 
Restart everything: AP, laptop, mobile phone. The server is not more reachable by my mobile phone. 
I can ping the IP address using a terminal app, but I can't access to it anymore. This, just changing the SSID. If I revert to "Zapp" SSID, everything work again.
I checked IP's: the change of SSID not change IP's of clients.

Could anyone explain and help?

Technical devices:
AP: TP-LINK TL-WR841R
Server WAMP v. 3.0.6 on a Toshiba Laptop
Android Phone OS 7.1 OnePlus3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Windows firewall profile. It might classify the network with the other SSID as Public and ports are not opened?

Comment: The new SSID (the one that doesn't work) is classificate as Public and I suppose this could be the trick. How can I change to Private?

Comment: In "Network and sharing Center" just click where it says "Public network" and select a new type.

Comment: Found this link and solved https://tinkertry.com/how-to-change-windows-10-network-type-from-public-to-private
Thanks @jared